Starting Azurite when debugging (F5) Azure Functions with VS Code
Does anyone know if there's a simple, recommended way to always background start/stop Azurite using a temp directory when F5 debugging in VS Code, like Visual Studio proper does, maybe through the launch.json? I have the Azurite installed, so I can manually start the service and it works, but I find all of the __*__ files in my project directory to be really annoying. Not to mention the Azurite: Clean command never cleans everything due to file-level locks. My environment is up to date and currently as follows:

OS: Windows 11 23H2 (OS Build 22631.3527)
VS Code: 1.89.1 (w/ Azure, Azure Functions and Azurite extensions)
Azure Function Core Tools: 4.0.5700
Model: dotnet-isolated
Language: C#
local.settings.json contains "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true"


This has been annoying me for years and I finally found an answer after digging into the Azure Functions issue log and finding Issue 3876. Until something is done to resolve this, the simple fix is to replace
{
  //...
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=True"
    // ...    
  }
}

with this
{
  //...
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=http;AccountName=devstoreaccount1;AccountKey=Eby8vdM02xNOcqFlqUwJPLlmEtlCDXJ1OUzFT50uSRZ6IFsuFq2UVErCz4I6tq/K1SZFPTOtr/KBHBeksoGMGw==;BlobEndpoint=http://127.0.0.1:10010/devstoreaccount1;QueueEndpoint=http://127.0.0.1:10011/devstoreaccount1;TableEndpoint=http://127.0.0.1:10012/devstoreaccount1;"
    // ...    
  }
}


I have followed below steps to create a .NET8 Isolated Blob Trigger Azure function and able to run the function without running the Azurite manually, also could avoid creating extra(__*__) files.

Open Command Palette in Visual Studio Code(Ctrl+shift+p), select Azure Functions: Create Function.



Select the Project folder, runtime and the function trigger.



Select Use Azurite Emulator for local storage.


The function gets created successfully.
local.settings.json:
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet-isolated"
  }
}


Start debugging the function, this will run successfully without creating any extra files in the project folder.

Output:
Executing task: C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe build /property:GenerateFullPaths=true /consoleloggerparameters:NoSummary 

MSBuild version 17.9.8+b34f75857 for .NET
  Determining projects to restore...
  All projects are up-to-date for restore.
  functionapp2 -> C:\Users\uname\Source\Repos\functionapp2\bin\Debug\net8.0\functionapp2.dll
  Determining projects to restore...
  Restored C:\Users\uname\AppData\Local\Temp\dba1mmm5.sng\WorkerExtensions.csproj (in 1.66 sec).
  WorkerExtensions -> C:\Users\uname\AppData\Local\Temp\dba1mmm5.sng\buildout\Microsoft.Azure.Fu
  nctions.Worker.Extensions.dll
 *  Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it. 

 *  Executing task: func host start 

Azure Functions Core Tools
Core Tools Version:       4.0.5700 Commit hash: N/A +71cc84964a60bfb07d95839b7c666bd239507bdd (64-bit)  
Function Runtime Version: 4.33.2.22572

[2024-05-14T12:16:01.703Z] Found C:\Users\uname\Source\Repos\functionapp2\functionapp2.csproj. Using fing for user secrets file configuration.
[2024-05-14T12:16:19.544Z] Worker process started and initialized.

Functions:

        BlobTrigger1: blobTrigger

For detailed output, run func with --verbose flag.
[2024-05-14T12:16:22.956Z] Executing 'Functions.BlobTrigger1' (Reason='New blob detected(LogsAndContainerScan): samples-workitems/Helloworld.txt', Id=f6aa2108-0112-4cc1-9faf-3bc8b892171d)
[2024-05-14T12:16:22.967Z] Trigger Details: MessageId: 48c33c25-80dc-40b6-977b-75ccee932de9, DequeueCount: 1, InsertedOn: 2024-05-14T12:16:22.000+00:00, BlobCreated: 2024-05-14T11:56:05.000+00:00, BlobLastModified: 2024-05-14T11:56:05.000+00:00
[2024-05-14T12:16:23.708Z] C# Blob trigger function Processed blob
 Name: Helloworld.txt
 Data:
[2024-05-14T12:16:23.796Z] Executed 'Functions.BlobTrigger1' (Succeeded, Id=f6aa2108-0112-4cc1-9faf-3bc8b892171d, Duration=975ms)
[2024-05-14T12:16:24.440Z] Host lock lease acquired by instance ID '000000000000000000000000F72731CC'. 


Folder Structure:

